# Is it ever more gas efficient to store address(0) as a variable constant?

Tags: solidity

I see that in many smart contracts `address(0)` is being used as shorthand for `0x0000000000....`
However since it appears very often in almost all smart contracts, I am wondering if it is, or ever becomes gas efficient to simply create the variable as constant in the blockchain instead, and just reference it when necessary, or if it really is just cheaper to constantly write `address(0)` inline every time.

`address public constant NULLADDRESS = address(0);` vs using `address(0)` inline 50 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i just tested this out with this code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract NullContract{
    address public constant NULLADDRESS = address(0);
    
    function retrieve() public pure returns(address){
        return (address(0));
    }
}
```

constant NULLADDRESS needed 21442 gas
and retrieve function which returns value doesn't change anything in the blockchain needed 21420 gas. so its basically the same